# Can you explain these three things in this bash code for me?

Tags: shell, sed, variable, function, cd-command

I have a `function` in my `.bashrc` file. I know what it does, it steps up X many directories with `cd`

Here it is:

```
up()
{
    local d=""
    limit=$1
    for ((i=1 ; i <= limit ; i++))
      do
        d=$d/..
      done
    d=$(echo $d | sed 's/^\///')
    if [ -z "$d" ]; then
      d=..
    fi
    cd $d
}
```

But can you explain these three things from it for me?

1. `d=$d/..`
2. `sed 's/^\///'`
3. `d=..`

Why not just do like this:

```
up()
{
    limit=$1

    for ((i=1 ; i <= limit ; i++))
    do
        cd ..
    done
}
```

Usage:

```
<<<>>>~$ up 3
<<<>>>/$
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. `d=$d/..` adds `/..` to the current contents of the `d` variable. `d` starts off empty, then the first iteration makes it `/..`, the second `/../..` etc.
2. `sed 's/^\///'` drops the first `/`, so `/../..` becomes `../..` (this can be done using a parameter expansion, `d=${d#/}`).
3. `d=..` only makes sense in the context of its condition:

   ```
   if [ -z "$d" ]; then
     d=..
   fi
   ```

   This ensures that, if `d` is empty at this point, you go to the parent directory. (`up` with no argument is equivalent to `cd ..`.)

This approach is better than iterative `cd ..` because it preserves `cd -` — the ability to return to the previous directory (from the user’s perspective) in one step.

The function can be simplified:

```
up() {
  local d=..
  for ((i = 1; i < ${1:-1}; i++)); do d=$d/..; done
  cd $d
}
```

This assumes we want to move up at least one level, and adds *n - 1* levels, so we don’t need to remove the leading `/` or check for an empty `$d`.

Using Athena `jot` (the `athena-jot` package in Debian):

```
up() { cd $(jot -b .. -s / "${1:-1}"); }
```

(based on a [variant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476253/can-you-explain-these-three-things-in-this-bash-code-for-me-please/476266?noredirect=1#comment870404_476266) suggested by [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman)).

Comment: Yep, `$OLDPWD` getting trampled on came to mind. And on zsh with `cd` set to use the dirstack, that too.

Comment: Is there some reason for assigning `$1` to `limit` instead of just using `$1` in the loop?

Comment: @kundor it ensures the default is 0 (see [shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic)). We could use `${1:-1}` instead, as in glenn’s variant.

Comment: @kundor Also human readability. A well-named variable tells you what the intended *meaning* or *purpose* of the first argument is when you *start* reading the function, without having to first know what the function does or finish understanding the code to deduce it.

Answer (score 2):

> But can you explain these three things from it for me?

1. d=$d/..

   This concatenates the present contents of var `d` with `/..` and assign it back to `d`.
   The end result is to make `d` a repeated string like `/../../../..`.
2. sed 's/^///'

   Remove the leading `/` from the string supplied, `d` (echo $d) in the code you posted.
   Probably better written as `sed 's|^/||'` to avoid the backslash.

   An alternative (faster and simpler) is to write `d=${d#/}`.
3. d=..

   Assign the string `..` to the var `d`.
   This only makes sense as a way to ensure that `d` has at least **one** `..` in case the test `if [ -z "$d" ]; then` signals that the var `d` is empty. 
   And that can only happen because the sed command is removing one character from `d`.
   If there is no need to remove the character from d, there is no need for `sed` or `if`.

---

The code in your question will always move up at least one dir.

## Better

- `local d` is enough to make sure that the variable is empty, nothing else is needed.
  However, local works only in some shells like bash or dash. In specific, `ksh` (as `yash`) doesn't have a `local` command. A more portable solution is:

  ```
  [ "$KSH_VERSION$YASH_VERSION" ] && typeset c='' d='' i='' || local c='' d='' i=''
  ```
- The `for((` syntax is not portable. Better use something like:

  ```
  while [ "$((i+=1))" -lt "$limit" ]; do
  ```
- Robust.
  If the values given to the function first argument could be negative or text, the function should be robust to process those values.
  First, lets limit the values to only numbers (I'll use `c` for `count`):

  ```
  c=${1%%[!0-9]*}
  ```

  And then limit the count value only to positive values:

  ```
  let "c = (c>0)?c:0"
  ```

This function will hapily accept 0 or any text (without errors):

```
up()
{
    [ "$KSH_VERSION$YASH_VERSION" ] && typeset c='' d='' i='' || local c='' d='' i=''
    c=${1%%[!0-9]*}
    c=$(((c>0)?c:0))
    while [ "$((i+=1))" -le "$c" ]; do d="$d../"; done
    echo \
        cd "${d%/}"         # Removing the trailing / is not really needed for cd
                            # but it is nice to know it could be done cleanly.
}

up 2
up 0
up asdf
```

Remove the `echo \` when you have tested the function.